# Multiple next.config.js configuration files in next.js

Tags: next.js

I in need of many `next.config.js` files (static/prod/dev etc).
How do I handle this?

`next build` doesn't have a `--config` option and I can't find env variable to overwrite the default config file name.

Ideally I'd like something like this: `next build --config next.config.production.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can use env variables inside `next.config.js` and this way have different configurations inside one `next.config.js`. For example:

```js
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');

const env = process.env.NEXT_CONFIG_ENV || 'development';

let nextConfig = {
  static: {
    
  },
  production: {
    
  },
  development: {
    
  },
}[env];

// Common config
nextConfig = {
  ...nextConfig,
  ...{
   
  }
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    
  ],
  nextConfig,
);
```